# Cloud function fails to invoke another cloud function when using different service accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-iam

I have 2 different cloud functions. The current setup is as follows:

- Cloud scheduler triggers function A
- Function A triggers function B at the end of the script using pub/sub
- Both cloud functions are 2nd gen and require authentication
- Both functions use different service accounts
- I have setup a pub/sub topic called `db-topic`

The function A publishing a message part works fine. But when when I check the logs of function B I get the following error:

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header
```

I created 2 different cloud functions like this:
Deploy http cloud function A:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy db-func-pubsub-test \
--runtime=python310 \
--trigger-http \
--entry-point=start_script \
--region=europe-west3 \
--max-instances=1 \
--timeout=3500s \
--memory=1GiB \
--service-account=cloud-function-a@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--ingress-settings=all \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--gen2 \
--source=./cloud_functions/code/6/publisher/
```

Deploy pubsub cloud function B:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy func-pubsub-subscriber-test \
--runtime=python310 \
--trigger-topic=db-topic \
--entry-point=pubsub_handler \
--region=europe-west3 \
--max-instances=1 \
--timeout=60s \
--memory=256MiB \
--service-account=cloud-function-b@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--ingress-settings=all \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--gen2 \
--source=./cloud_functions/code/6/subscriber/
```

And grant permission to allow function A to invoke function B:

```bash
gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding func-pubsub-subscriber-test \
    --member="serviceAccount:cloud-function-a@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --region='europe-west3'
```

I don't know why function A does not have the permission to invoke function B? I used the same method to grant cloud scheduler the access to invoke function a and that worked fine.
Also if I use the same service account for both cloud functions it also works fine.

**Edit:**
The code is working 100% because this whole setup works if I use the same service account for both cloud functions but I'll provide my code anyway just in case.

Function A code:

```py
# Publish a message to the Pub/Sub topic
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = f'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}'
    data = {"project_id": project_id, "bucket_name": bucket_name, "prefix_path": prefix_path}
    data_str = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')  # Convert dictionary to JSON-encoded bytestring
    publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data_str)
    print(f"Printing json message being published: {data}")
```

Function B code:

```py
def pubsub_handler(event, context):
    # Retrieve the JSON payload from the Pub/Sub message
    pubsub_message = event['data']
    decoded_message = base64.b64decode(pubsub_message).decode('utf-8')  # Decode and convert to string
    print(f"Printing pubsub message received: {decoded_message}")
    data_dict = json.loads(decoded_message)
```

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/7UYAl1q.png) are all roles that are granted to the service account of function A.

**Edit 2:**
So I just noticed that the service account of function A does not have the permissions to publish messages actually. That's why I got error in the function A logs. I fixed that by running:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding propane-nomad-396712 --member=serviceAccount:cloud-function-a@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/pubsub.publisher
```

Then I also noticed that I probably don't have granted any permissions for the service account of function B to receive pub/sub messages. So I ran the following:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding propane-nomad-396712 --member=serviceAccount:cloud-function-b@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/pubsub.subscriber
```

I can successfully publish messages with function A now. But I still get the same error in function B as mentioned above

Comment: Can you share the code of A when it calls B?

Comment: Function A is not calling Function B. Function A should be publishing a message. Pub/Sub then calls Function B. From the CLI execute this command `gcloud pubsub topics publish db-topic --message="YOUR MESSAGE"` and verify that Function B is triggered. If that works, then the problem is with Function A. If it does not work, then debug Pub/Sub -> Function B,

Comment: Add to your post, the IAM roles assigned to `cloud-function-a@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: @JohnHanley So I added the permissions to publish messages for function A (that does work now) and to receive messages for function B but it still does not work. I can also manually publish a message using the gcloud command you provided just fine but the function b log still gives me the same error

Comment: I do not see an IAM role that allows Function A to publish to Pub/Sub. You need to add something like `roles/pubsub.publisher`.

Comment: As mentioned in my edit 2 I just added this permission via gcloud. Here is an updated picture of the permissions of [function a](https://i.imgur.com/B9yb4Tk.png) and here from [function b](https://i.imgur.com/OUrL1HB.png)

Comment: Excuse my misunderstanding. But if PubSub invokes Cloud Functions B, you have to show the PubSub push subscription configuration. You might create nothing but the CLI did it for you. Can you check the configuration? the service account used? The configuration to invoke the HTTP endpoint (security part especially)?

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly but the command I used to create the pub/sub topic was the following: ```gcloud pubsub topics create db-topic```
Also here is a picture of the [subscribers](https://i.imgur.com/XMr1aqw.png) of the topic. The other subscription listed here (without the -test) uses the default compute service account and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to get it working. At the end of the day there were 3 things needed to make it work:

1. Grant the service account A the permission to publish pub/sub messages

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding propane-nomad-396712 \
  --member=serviceAccount:cloud-function-a@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role=roles/pubsub.publisher
```

2. Grant the service account B the permission to receive pub/sub messages

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding propane-nomad-396712 \
  --member=serviceAccount:cloud-function-b@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role=roles/pubsub.receiver
```

3. Grant the service account B the permission to invoke cloud function B

```bash
gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding func-pubsub-subscriber-test \
    --member="serviceAccount:cloud-function-b@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --region='europe-west3'
```